# WP8.1: Cortana uri association?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

Does Cortana have a uri association, or another way to be launched from other apps?

I already tried

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("cortana:///"));

await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-cortana:///"));
```

but they don't work...

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a few months after this was asked, but for anyone else looking to launch Cortana you can do it by calling this:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("bing://home"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a cleaner way, but you can take advantage of the fact that the Cortana/Bing search page is displayed when the user try to load the Bing website.

So you can hide a WebBrowser control in your page (by setting its visibility to collapsed), then navigate to Bing when you want to launch Cortana:

```
this.WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
```

Comment: Great solution +1. Of course be mindful that in the many countries where Cortana is not yet deployed, this hack will then just launch Bing Search.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in Windows 10 TH2/RS1 *(Which I've tested by now)*, Cortana has supports following ***undocumented*** **Uri**s:

- ms-cortana://
- ms-cortana://StartMode=Coobe
- ms-cortana://StartMode=Reminders
- ms-cortana://StartMode=Notebook
- ms-cortana://StartMode=Settings

And there is [blog](http://www.cnblogs.com/ms-uap/p/5566129.html) posted by Chinese UWP App Team. :smile:

Answer (score 0):

Well at least on Windows 10, the way to launch Cortana in listening mode is using this Uri:  ms-cortana://Reactive/?StartMode=Reactive&ListeningMode=True

Test it in Edge, it works for me. Doesn't seem to work in Chrome though (as of this time).

Answer (score 0):

Cortana does support a few "deep linking" capabilities. You need a registered protocol handler installed (that is the case for W10 desktop by default.)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Cortana-Skills-Kit-Blog/Skill-Shortcut-Share-your-Cortana-Skill-with-users/ba-p/154484