# Is there a way to give Cortana a text command through the URI?

Tags: uwp, cortana

So I am referencing this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695856/wp8-1-cortana-uri-association). Basically, right now I am using the URI to launch Cortana in listening mode in a UWP Unity App. Something like this:

```
ms-cortana://Reactive/?StartMode=Reactive&ListeningMode=True
```

However, is there a way to launch Cortana and give it a string with what I want to say? For example, launching Cortana with a string variable sent to the URI like "Call ContactName" or "What's the weather like today".

My user would use something like a list to select pre-defined commands because maybe some reason they are mute or their mic quits working.

Comment: Did you check this link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/launch-apps-from-skills

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some search content, you could use the following format:

```
ms-cortana://search/?q={0}
```

For example: `ms-cortana://search/?q=What's the weather like today`

Comment: This partly answers my question. Is there a URI I can use through Cortana to get access to skype or send a message to someone? I know there is a skype uri but it does not work for this purpose. It has to be through Cortana.

Comment: What I mean is right now all that URI does is basically search the internet.